# Change Boostrap Card CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

The defeault style of the Bootstrap card on my website is light but I have javascript that turns my site theme dark during certain hours in the evening/early morning. I am trying to change the style of the Bootstrap card to dark. I have linked the code below but it does not work as expected.

```js
let hour = new Date().getHours();

if(hour < 14 || hour > 20) {
    darkMode();
}

function darkMode() {
  var element_body = document.body;
  element_body.classList.toggle("dark-mode-body");

  var links = document.querySelector("a");

  /* returns first anchor tag within the document */

  links.classList.toggle("dark-mode-anchor");

  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card bg-light");

  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].classList.toggle("card bg-dark");
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-light">
  <div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
  <p class="card-text">Some example text. Some example text.</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-light mr-0" role="button">Card link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add the bg-dark class. You code is currently raising an error, as you cannot toggle multiple classes with `classList.toggle`.

Change

```
cards[i].classList.toggle("card bg-dark");
```

To

```
cards[i].classList.add("bg-dark");
```

To change each button within a card to have a dark style as well, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` and remove the btn-light class and add the btn-dark class.

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".card a.btn");
btns.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.classList.remove("btn-light");
    btn.classList.add("btn-dark");
});
```

Comment: how would i be able to change the button color? change it from light to dark

Comment: @TrevorTocchet You can do `document.querySelector('a.btn').classList.remove("btn-light")` and `document.querySelector('a.btn').classList.add("btn-dark")`.

Comment: @TrevorTocchet How many buttons are there? `document.querySelector` only selects the first matching element.

Comment: I only want it to affect the buttons that are within the Bootstrap cards (there are multiple of them) but the above code affects the first button on each page of the site.